# Verbose useradd in Red Hat Enterprise Linux

Tags: linux, useradd

I'm trying to output the result of "useradd" to a logfile, but unfortunately there is no verbose option. For example: "useradd dude" has no output, unless the user already exists.

I would like to do something similar to: useradd -v dude > $logfile

I suppose I could check the result code and if 0 query the user's UID and GID and write it to the logfile, for example:

```
log=logfile
un=dude
if useradd ${un} &>> $log; then
  uu=$(getent passwd ${un} | cut -d: -f3)
  ug=$(getent passwd ${un} | cut -d: -f4)
  uh=$(getent passwd ${un} | cut -d: -f6)
  echo "User ${un} UID:${uu} GID:${ug} ${uh} successfully added." >> $log
fi 


# cat logfile
User dude UID:1000 GID:1000 /home/dude successfully added.
useradd: user 'dude' already exists
```

but I wonder if there's an easier option.

OS: RHEL 7.7

Parsing /var/log/secure might be another idea:

```
un=dude
useradd ${un} 2>&- &
bpid=$!
wait $bpid
ret=$?
sync
(grep "useradd\[${bpid}\]" /var/log/secure | tail -n 2) >> logfile

if [[ ${ret} -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo do whatever you need to do
else
  echo error
  exit 1
fi

# ./abc
do whatever you need to do
# ./abc
error

# cat logfile
Aug 24 03:48:07 vm7031 useradd[4929]: new group: name=dude, GID=1000
Aug 24 03:48:07 vm7031 useradd[4929]: new user: name=dude, UID=1000, GID=1000, home=/home/dude, shell=/bin/bash
Aug 24 03:48:09 vm7031 useradd[4940]: failed adding user 'dude', exit code: 9
```

It seems to require a sync though, otherwise grep won't work. Not sure, seems all a bit overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems useradd or adduser options are more limited on RHEL 7 compared to other distributions. I've decided to do the following:

```
useradd ${un} 2>&- &
pid=$!; wait $pid; sync
{ grep "useradd\[${pid}\]" ${authlog} | tail -n 2; } >> ${logfile}

Then I simply verify whether the user exists and continue accordingly.
```

This will execute useradd in the background, which is necessary so that $! will show me the PID of that particular process. It will then search /var/log/secure for the process ID in reverse order and write the output to my own logfile. A sync or pause (sleep 3) is necessary, but it should not hurt performance.

Answer (score 2):

### OPTION 1 (RHEL,DEBIAN)

Here are two additional possibilities available to RHEL, based on inotify-tools (these are not installed by default as far as I remember). The `/dev/null` pipe is to prevent stdout to the terminal, because -qq was not as quiet as described.

For **DEBIAN** distributions, change  **`/var/log/secure`** to **`/var/log/auth.log`**, and obviously `sudo` , but actually logging in as `root` - to set up this type of system-wide monitoring - might actually be one of those appropriate usages of `root`.

**1.Monitoring the `/var/log/secure` changes in the background:**

```
    while inotifywait -qq -e modify /var/log/secure; 
       do 
       if tail -n1 /var/log/secure | grep useradd > /dev/null; 
         then 
           tail -n1 /var/log/secure | grep useradd >> ~/useradd.log; 

           echo "Here you can also add conditional action if user already exists";    

       fi; 
    done &
```

I really like this particular option because it allows compartamentalization of different parts (useradd, pam etc.) of the `auth.log` or `secure` logs into separately monitored sublogs.

**2.Monitoring usage of `useradd` command itself**

```
while inotifywait -qq /usr/sbin/useradd; 
   do  
    if tail -n1 /var/log/secure | grep useradd > /dev/null; 
        then  tail -n1 /var/log/secure | grep useradd >> ~/useradd.log ;          
    fi; 
  done  &
```

Either option packaged as a script and executed with `nohup [script] > /dev/null` will monitor continuously in the background even when the terminal gets closed.

### OPTION 2 (DEBIAN)

Or even better option in your case might be to use `adduser` instead and create `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` which will be executed after `adduser` command completes

if you create `adduser.local` as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

# arguments passed in the following order: username uid gid home-directory
    #adjust log path accordingly

echo "ADDUSER: $1 $2 $3 $4 $5" >> ~/adduser.log
```

This should get the logfile appended whenever a new user gets created

### OPTION 3 (ALL)

Yes, the output of `useradd` actually gets appended to `/var/log/auth.log`

tested it as an example (sudo before commands obviously)

```
$useradd dude
$cat /var/log/auth.log | tail -2

Aug 23 19:01:25 useradd[32230]: new group: name=dude, GID=1012
Aug 23 19:01:25 useradd[32230]: new user: name=dude, UID=1011, GID=1012, home=/home/dude, shell=/bin/sh

$useradd dude
$cat /var/log/auth.log | tail -1 

Aug 23 19:04:16 useradd[32328]: failed adding user 'dude', data deleted
```

All in all, I believe what you are looking for is:

```
$ sudo grep -a "useradd" /var/log/auth.log
```

And that will give you all the log entries with the names and times users were added to the system.

Comment: That's not a bad idea, but what are the odds? For example, someone could login in at the very same time, thus tail catching the wrong log. It would be best to query the PID. Btw, RHEL 7 uses /var/log/secure.

Comment: Also, I just need the log of the specific user, not all of them.

Comment: I completely forgot that you can also use `adduser [username] --debug ` for more verbose output when adding users

Comment: Additionally with `adduser` you can extend that command by adding `/usr/local/sbin/adduser.local` which will be executed after adduser completes. I updated my answer

Comment: But then again, I cannot guarantee you will have adduser on RHEL

Comment: adduser is simply a symlink to useradd. I tried --debug, but it shows "unrecognized option '--debug'". RH apparently doesn't like it. Again, useradd or adduser has no output to screen unless there's an error.

Comment: yeah, I was afraid of that in RHEL . Under debian , useradd and adduser are very different commands in terms of additional options allowed. However, yet another option just occured to me, let me just quickly double-check if it is a viable one RHEL. I have one question though: is the logging being done for security purposes, or for simple compartmentalized storing of useradd information , because security-wise users with useradd permissions will be able to circumvent most of the straighforward ones)

Comment: I have a setup script that will add a regular user account in case the user doesn't exist. It is run as root, obviously, and generating it's own setup log file. I simply want to lot the results of the useradd command in the setup log file. If the user cannot be created the procedure will show an error and exit, though I could not think of a reason why this could happen.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't need to monitor /var/log/secure. That's not what I'm trying to accomplish.